# CSS, given the className of parent element and child element, how to select the child?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a Reactjs project where I have a below components:
I want to hide the div that has a className 'tool' when body has className 'hasModal', and show the 'tool' div when I remove the className 'hasModal'.
I know how to remove and add className by using document.body.classList.add/remove
And I am using display:none to hide the element.
But I do not know how to select the 'tool'element.

```
<body class="hasModal">
 ...
 many levels of div
 ...
  <div class="tool">
  </div>
</div>
```

My first intent is to use body.hasModal > div.tool{display: none}, but nothing happened, I can still see the div;
I try to use .hasModal.tool {display: none} but that does not take effect;
I also use .hasModal>.tool{display:none} but this can not work either.
Can someone help me with this? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`.hasModal > .tool` will not work, because `tool` has to be a direct child of `hasModal` and you have "many levels of div" between them.

```css
.b {
  background-color: red;
}

.a > .b {
  background-color: teal;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    works
  </div>
</div>

<div class="a">
  <div class="whatever">
    <div class="b">
      works not
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`.hasModal.tool` will not work because it selects all elements that have both classes `hasModal` and `tool`.

```css
.b {
  background-color: red;
}

.a.b {
  background-color: teal;
}
```

```html
<div class="a b">
    works
</div>

<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    works not
  </div>
</div>
```

You should use the "Descendant combinator" which is just a space.

```css
.b {
  background-color: red;
}

.a .b {
  background-color: teal;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    works
  </div>
</div>

<div class="a">
  <div class="whatever">
    <div class="b">
      works!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors for the details of CSS selectors and how their combinators work.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Much better than mine

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply!

Answer (score 2):

It's fairly simple to do this:

```css
.hasModal .tool {
  display: none;
}
```

In CSS, to select a descendant of a class you can use a space between the class names as above.

Additionally you should refer to [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) for more information on CSS selectors